# border highlighting loop with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble coming up with a loop that changes the border color of an image from black to yellow and yellow to black over x seconds. Then applying an interrupt to the loop when the image gets clicked on. I don't know where to start, can someone point me in the right direction? I think I may be using the wrong tools to properly write this.

Here's what I've come up so far, though if there's a better way to write this, do share!

```
for( i = 100; i >= 0; i--)
{
$("#imgid").css("border-color", 'rgb(' + i + '%,' + i + '%,0)');
}
```

There's three parts I'd like to know.

1.)I'm having trouble picturing how I could combine two loops so that I can also count upwards as well so that it will turn into yellow and back to black *without stopping*. Or can I accomplish this with one loop?

2.)Slow the loop to be able to control the amount of seconds for the border fading effect.

2.)How to break the loop with an onclick() event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good place to start would be using the module pattern. Here is a base to work from, it will do the first animation:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ue4wy/1/

I'll try add the click interrupt, as that can be tricky with scope.

[Edit]

Here you go: click working and everything

http://jsfiddle.net/Ue4wy/4/

[/Edit]

Code:

```
var anim = (function() {
    var i = 0;
    var step = 10;
    var up = true;
    var timer = null;

    var next = function() {
        if (up) {
            i += step;
        }
        else {
            i -= step;
        }
        if(i<0){i=0; up=true;}
        if(i>255){i=255; up=false;}
        update();
    };

    var update = function() {
        $("div").css("border-color", 'rgb(' + i + ',' + i + ',' + 0 + ')');
    };

    var go = function() {
        next();
        timer = window.setTimeout(anim.go, 30);
    };

    var stop = function() {
        if (timer) {
            window.clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = null;
        }
    };

    var addClickHandler = function() {
        $("div").click(function() {
            if(timer){
                anim.stop();
            }
            else{
                anim.go();
            }
        });
    };

    return {
        go: go,
        stop: stop,
        addClickHandler: addClickHandler 
    };
}());

anim.addClickHandler();
anim.go();
```

Comment: +1 can you copy the answer here? anyhow, it's cool seeing it in action :-)

Comment: it's fairly big... I guess i could

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/

In your code, you would set up a timer with `$.doTimeout`.  Use a variable to keep track of the current state of the border.

Play with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/JZ62H/4/
It works now.

All the javascript at the top is from the first link.

To change the rate all you have to do is change the `2` in this line of code (it appears twice):

```
$.doTimeout('timerid', 2, doIt);
```

I added a resume functionality too.

Comment: I edited my question to reflect that there are a few other parts that I needed answered.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example:

```
for (i=0;i<=10;i++)
  {
  if (i==3)
    {
    break;
    }
  document.write("The number is " + i);
  document.write("<br />");
  }
```

Instead of i == 3 you can look for your event...etc:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Also look at [Creating Delays in JS](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/timers)

Comment: wanted to -1 your answer, not enough jQuery :D lol! http://doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif

Answer (score 0):

Don't handle animation by yourself, if you're already using jQuery, the building basic blocks are already there:

- jQuery has `.animate()`, which:
- can be given CSS to animate to,
- can be given a speed of animation
- can be given a callback function which will be called when the animation completes
- but, doesn't handle colors out of the box, you'll need the [color animation plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) (very lightweight, written by jQuery's author)

Using these, here's how I'd build what you want:

```
var stop = false; // a flag for the click handler to tell the animation to stop

function highlight() {
   // Animate to yellow, 1000 milliseconds
   $("#imgId").animate({borderColor: "yellow"}, 1000, function () {
      // Exit if the flag is set, remove this line if
      // you want it to always fade to black before stopping.
      if (stop) return;
      // Now animate back to black
      $("#imgId").animate({borderColor: "black"}, 1000, function () {
         // Keep animating if the flag isn't set
         if (!stop) highlight();
      });
   });
}

// Start the loop
highlight();

// Click handler
$("#imgId").click(function () {
   stop = true;
});
```

Comment: Ah, I tried to do something similar but it seems that it was because I was missing the color animation plugin.