# 'Pulsing' a border in Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am in the process of applying validation on a web form  -one of the things I would like to do is add a pulsing border to the div which contains the erroneous input.

This solution: [border highlighting loop with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505262/border-highlighting-loop-with-jquery) and http://jsfiddle.net/Ue4wy/4/ pretty much hits the mark.

But I want to be able to fade the yellow border to black on the click handler & reset the loop (this example pauses the loop), so the next time the user hits submit it starts again.

Reseting the colour to black works using the code below (though I am sure there is a more elegant solution), but how do I reset the loop?

```
    $('#weight').animate({
        borderBottomColor: '#000',
        borderLeftColor: '#000',
        borderRightColor: '#000',
        borderTopColor : '#000'
    }, 'fast' );
```

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Ue4wy/15/? The code you've shown already has a click handler that stops the animation, so just add to that part to reset the border to black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the `update()` function to accept an argument, `i`, which is then called in the click handler, along with `window.clearTimeout()`:

```
var addClickHandler = function() {
    $("div").click(function() {
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
        update(0);

    });
};
```

This does require that the other calls to `update()` *also* need to pass the `i`:

```
var update = function(i) {
    $("div").css("border-color", 'rgb(' + i + ',' + i + ',' + 0 + ')');
};
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ue4wy/16/).

---

**Edited** to amend the click-handler to offer a toggle (stop/start) for the animation:

```
var addClickHandler = function() {
    $("div").toggle(function() {
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
        update(0);

    }, function() {
        anim.go();
    });
};
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ue4wy/17/).

---

**Edited** for a slightly more context-aware click-handler, this version checks for the existence of the `timer` variable and, if it isn't found, starts the animation. If it *is* found then it clears the timeout, sets the `timer` to `false` and calls `update(0)` to reset the borders to black:

```
var addClickHandler = function() {
    $("div").click(function() {
        console.log(timer);
        if (!timer){
            timer = window.setTimeout(anim.go, 30);
        }
        else {
            window.clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = false;
            update(0);
        }

    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ue4wy/18/).

References:

- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).
- [`window.clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed; I'm glad to have been of help! =)

Comment: Wow, i only just got the first fiddle working! Lol!  Is there any way to make the reset smoother - ie: fade to black rather than jump? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jQuery UI effect to pulsate the border:

```
$.effects.borderPulsate = function(o) {
    return this.queue(function() {
        var elem = $(this),
            mode = $.effects.setMode(elem, o.options.mode || 'show'),
            times = (o.options.times || 5),
            duration = o.duration ? o.duration : $.fx.speeds._default,
            isVisible = elem.is(':visible'),
            color = (o.options.color || 'rgb(255,255,0)'),
            startColor = (o.options.startColor || elem.css('border-color') || 'transparent');

        if (!isVisible) {
            elem.show();
        }

        if ((mode == 'hide' && isVisible) || (mode == 'show' && !isVisible)) {
            times--;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            elem.animate({ 'border-color': color }, duration, o.options.easing, function() {
                elem.css( 'border-color', startColor );
            });
        }

        elem.animate({ 'border-color': color }, duration, o.options.easing, function() {
            (o.callback && o.callback.apply(this, arguments));
        });

        elem
            .queue('fx', function() { elem.dequeue(); })
            .dequeue();
    });
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cdeutsch/TjkNd/

Comment: not working w/o jquery UI lib, i'm looking for pulsate border w/o adding all big UI lib

Comment: Correct, my answer says: "Here's a jQuery UI effect to pulsate the border:" Notice, the "jQuery UI" part. ;)

Comment: noticed after trying. I'm trying to keep my load time <300ms perfectly <200ms so i don't want to use big libraries for small things

Comment: You can always try a customer jQuery UI build to make it smaller http://jqueryui.com/download/ (start with just the Effects Core)

Comment: yes i know, still too much code for simple highlight thing, i've done it with css & basic jQuery

Comment: I'm sure the people that come across this question would love if you shared that as an answer here. ;)

Comment: it's just 1 line of code :) i needed to highlight check boxes, because if user is trying to do X action, he has to check checkbox, so my "highlight" is as simple as this: $('.question-batch-actions-row').css('outline', '1px solid red');

Answer (score 0):

You can change colors on all borders at the same time with `borderColor`, but you don't need to animate that. You could add a reset method to your object to take care of the whole thing:

```
var reset = function() {
    i = 0;
    step = 10;
    up = true;
    if(timer) window.clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = null;
    $('#weight').css('borderColor', '#000');
}
```

Then on your click handler, you call `anim.reset()` after `anim.stop()`.