# Make border of input box pulsate on load

Tags: jquery, css

Anyone know how I can get the border color of this input box to fade in to a yellow, then fade out, then fade back in, then fade out again (pulsate twice) on page load using jquery? After the pulsating, the border color should be set to transparent. I tried a variety of settimeouts but nothing seemed to work. Please help and thank you!!

```
<input type="search" id="searches" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Search" onclick="select();">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with CSS3:

```
#searches {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 0.7s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 2;
  animation: pulse 0.7s;
  animation-iteration-count: 2;
  background: white;
  outline: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  from { border-color: transparent; }
  50% { border-color: yellow; }
  to { border-color: transparent; }
}
@keyframes pulse {
  from { border-color: transparent; }
  50% { border-color: yellow; }
  to { border-color: transparent; }
}
```

jsFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/spXH8/1/

If you really need it done with jQuery (for IE support or something), see the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9651435/507629) of ['Pulsing' a border in Javascript/JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651342/pulsing-a-border-in-javascript-jquery).